# XMLWorkerHelper convert html page into pdf produces only first 2 pages

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, itext, xmlworker

I'm getting only the first two page. I have a generated list of elements in the third page. When there are too many elements in my collection, all pages from there become blank in my pdf output

```
  using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
                {                        
                    Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 25, 25, 30, 30);
                    WebClient wc = new WebClient();
                    string htmlText = wc.DownloadString(textUrl);                      

                    PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, fs);
                    document.Open();
                      // register all fonts in current computer
                    FontFactory.RegisterDirectories(); 
                    XMLWorkerFontProvider fontProvider = new XMLWorkerFontProvider();
                    using (var msHtml = new MemoryStream(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetBytes(htmlText)))
                    {
                        //Set factories
                        var cssAppliers = new CssAppliersImpl(fontProvider);
                        var htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(cssAppliers);

                        //HtmlPipelineContext htmlContext = new HtmlPipelineContext(null);
                        htmlContext.SetTagFactory(Tags.GetHtmlTagProcessorFactory());

                        //FontFactory.Register(arialuniTff);
                        string gishaTff = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "GISHA.TTF");
                        FontFactory.Register(gishaTff);

                        var worker = XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance();
                        var cssStream = new FileStream(FolderMapPath("/css/style.css"), FileMode.Open);

                        worker.ParseXHtml(pdfWriter, document, msHtml, cssStream, new UnicodeFontFactory());
                    }

                    // Close the document
                    document.Close();

                    // Close the writer instance
                    pdfWriter.Close();
                }
```

Here is my cshtml code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i solved my problem. The problem wasn't with the C# backend code. It's seems like the **XMLWorkerHelper** at the moment doesn't deal well with loop in view. I had to display list of items in my PDF file. The result was well if the collection contains no so many items, But the page break at the level when the the collection contains more than 50 items because this could not be display in a single page. What i did is that i started to count the number of items and at some number like 40, i just include a break element `<li style="list-style:none; list-style-type:none; page-break-before:always">@item</li>`. And reset the counter and continue display my items. And it was great and my problem was resolved. 
May be this can be helpful for someone.

Answer (score 0):

I only have experience working with iText in Java, but is it possible that the MemoryStream object you are using has a byte limit that gets filled up when the table on page 3 has too many elements for it to store? If that's the case, then the closing tags on that long table may not be written to the MemoryStream, thus that table and everything after doesn't get rendered; i.e. get's truncated by the PDF converter engine.

Can you try using a different Stream object?

Comment: Thanks. I just added an answer how i resolved that problem. may be it could be for some help for others.